# What is the time complexity for inserting n elements in a stack using a linked list?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Each insertion in a stack is O(1) so is the time taken to insert 'n' elements O(n) ? 
Can we speak similarly for a hash-table as well ? In average case the time taken to insert 'n' elements in a hash table = O(n) ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The dominating factor is not the insert time, which is constant, its the time it takes to iterate over all the things you are inserting.  If inserting did not happen in constant time, it would be more complicated.

Note that in the HashTable case a lot depends on if the HashTable has to grow itself or rehash everything in it when that happens, but for the simple case (i.e. assuming the table is big enough to hold everything, and your hashcode generation does not generate collisions) the upper bound on insert should be n.

Comment: Big enough, and the hash values are evenly-distributed enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Each insertion in a stack is O(1) so is the time taken to insert 'n' elements O(n) ? 
>   Can we speak similarly for a hash-table as well ? In average case the time taken to 
>   insert 'n' elements in a hash table = O(n) ?

As you mentioned *stack* , I assume we resolve collisions in hashtable using *stack* ([in chaining manner, using closed addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) ).

In such case I answer:

Yes, "average case the time taken to insert 'n' elements in a hash table = O(n)".

To be more specific. As inserting to hash table in your case is :

- making hash = O(1)
- inserting into stack selected with hash = O(1)

Whole hash insertion is O(1). So *n* operations is O(n).

My advice : be very specific on your exam about your assumptions (structures you use, their implementation and complexity) as all those details might have significant impact on result of all equations.